# SSL socket server get certificate cn after handshake

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jsse, mutual-authentication

I have an SSL socket server running with a 2-side handshake required (for which I'm using self signed certificates). After the handshake was successful, I would like to check the client certificate's cn on the server side. Unfortunately this field is set to `Unknown`.

Here is the code I used to determine the cn field value:

```
((SSLSocket) socket).addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent hce) {
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)hce.getLocalCertificates()[0];
        String certName = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName().substring(3,cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName().indexOf(","));
        System.out.println(certName);
    }
});
```

Which prints `Unknown`

Aditionally, I checked the client's keyStore using this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore clientStore.jks
```

Which prints

```
Keystore-type: JKS
Keystore-provider: SUN

Keystore contains 1 entry

Aliasname: test
creation date: 23.04.2018
entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
certificate length: 1
certificate[1]:
owner: CN=test, OU="Org Unit", O=Org, L=City, ST=State, C=DE
...
```

As you can see, the client store's certificate's cn is set. However it is inexplicable to me why it then seems not to be transmitted to the server.

I would be glad for every kind of help.

Best regards,

Galveston01

Comment: What happens if you do `System.out.println(cert);`?

Comment: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: CN=Unknown, OU="Org Unit", O=Org, L=City, ST=State, C=DE Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the handshake was successful, I would like to check the client
>   certificate's cn on the server side.

To check what certificates you have received you need to call [getPeerCertificates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HandshakeCompletedEvent.html#getPeerCertificates()) instead of getLocalCertificates, which is for the certificates you sent.

And you should read carefully the doc :

> public X500Principal getSubjectX500Principal()
>
> Returns the subject (subject distinguished name) value from the
>   certificate as an X500Principal. If the subject value is empty, then
>   the getName() method of the returned X500Principal object returns an
>   empty string ("").

For this reason it's not recommended to call `indexOf() substring()` without checking first the input.